# Apex - SalesForce - Writing Test case for a Trigger

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code, testcase

**Hello Folks,
I am really new to Apex Development and currently trying to write a test case for this trigger. Any kinds of help is really appreciated!**

```
trigger Milestone1_Expense_Trigger on Milestone1_Expense__c (before insert, before update) 
{
    if(Trigger.isBefore)
    {
        Milestone1_Expense_Trigger_Utility.handleExpenseBeforeTrigger(Trigger.new);
    }
}
```

**Thanks in Advance!**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @superfell Well, I was looking for help not for the link on 'how to ask the questions'. I did my homework and did not find anything useful so I came here and asked the question.

Comment: you didn't mention what you'd tried, where you looked or anything, you need to provide much more info if you want a useful answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the link matthew provided. That should give you an idea on what needs to be done and how you assert and confirm if what you are trying to do is actually happening.
If i were to explain it in a simple way.

Your trigger would get fired when an record is inserted/updated in Milestone1_Expense__c.
So in your test class all you need to do create a test data for Milestone1_Expense__c and give an insert statement.

if i were to give an example for Account

```
    Account a = new Account(Name = 'test', Company__c = 'test');
    insert a;
```

instead of Account here you can give use your custom object  and use the fields in that custom object

Answer (score 2):

Check out this introduction to [Apex Code Test Methods](http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods), and look for the code block that has the `http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods`. That code section is an example of testing an Apex Trigger.